# Is it bad practice to set the velocity of an object every loop?

Tags: box2d

Say I have a simple game with a `gameLoop` function that gets called every 50 milliseconds or something similar, and I have a box2d object. Is it bad practice/too CPU intensive to use `SetLinearVelocity` on the object every time the `gameLoop` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only bad if you find this to be detrimental to the performance of your game. I find it unlikely that setting the velocity directly would be very expensive.

If you do find that this is an issue, by profiling the code, you can create a simple function that only updates the box2D object's velocity if your external velocity value has changed. Something like:

```
if(velocity != oldVelocity) {
    box2DObject.SetLinearVelocity(velocity);
    oldVelocity = velocity;
}
```

Comment: Most physics engines don't like it much if you're setting velocity directly, instead of applying accelerations (or even better, impulses);  it often leads to bad behaviour in collisions.  But no, there's no CPU performance reason not to do it.

Comment: Make sure its a kinematic bodytype and the are no worries about the engine handling it incorrectly.